How to properly use Prisma Accelerate and Supabase with getting errrors?
//.env
DATABASE_URL="prisma://accelerate.prisma-data.net/?api_key=[api_key]"
DIRECT_URL="postgresql://postgres.[password]@aws-0-eu-central- 
1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres?connection_limit=10&pool_timeout=10"

//lib.prisma.ts

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client/edge";
import { withAccelerate } from "@prisma/extension-accelerate";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient().$extends(withAccelerate());
};

declare const globalThis: {
  prismaGlobal: ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
} & typeof global;

export const prismadb = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prismaGlobal = prismadb;

//Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:


Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(PostgresError { code: "42P05", message: "prepared statement \"s0\" already exists", severity: "ERROR", detail: None, column: None, hint: None }), transient: false })

I am using Prisma ORM and Supabase for my database, and to use Hono, I had to enable Prisma Accelerate. Since then, I have been getting many errors every time I use the database. The error above is the one that I am getting frequently. I used the Prisma docs to set up Prisma Accelerate, so I don't have many resources on this error.
I would appreciate it if anyone knew how to solve this error.
Thanks in advance.
